# About subspace of locally compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In Folland's Real Analysis, page 134, exercise 49c, is written, if X is compact Hausedorff space and E is subset of X, E is locally compact iff **E is open in closure of E** (**proposition 1**)

[We use usual definition of loc. compactness: We say that X is loc. conpact space is for every x from X, there exist x's compact neibourhood.]

In Engelking's General Topology, page 150, corollary 3.3.10, is written, if X is locally compact Hausedorff space and E is subset of X, E is locally compact iff *E can represent as intersection of V and F where V is open in X and F is close in X* (*proposition 2*).

{In Engelkings book, loc. compactness has little bit other definition: X is loc. compact (by Engelking) is for every x from X, there exist E open set such that x is in E and closure of E is compact. But loc. compactness (by folland) + Hausedorffness implies loc. compactness (by Engelking).

But meybe its easy to prove that proposition 1 and proposition 2 is equivalent (meybe my prove is correct). Than this mean that, folland in his exercise gives weak version of general proposition: it is true for loc. compact spaces and not only for compact spaces. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are indeed equivalent.

$E$ is open in $\operatorname{cl}E$ if and only if there is an open $V\subseteq X$ such that $E=V\cap\operatorname{cl}E$, so if $E$ is open in $\operatorname{cl}E$, then $E$ is the intersection of an open set and a closed set in $X$.

Now suppose that $E=V\cap F$, where $V$ is open, and $F$ is closed. Then $E\subseteq F$, so $\operatorname{cl}E\subseteq F$, and therefore $E\subseteq V\cap\operatorname{cl}E\subseteq V\cap F=E$; thus, $E=V\cap\operatorname{cl}E$, so $E$ is open in $\operatorname{cl}E$.

Comment: My prove was same. I wondered when I understand that equivalence, why in Folland's exercise not was general version of proposition. Meybe because if X is compact, proposition is easy to prove and because author white weak version of proposition in exercises.

Comment: And there is third equivalent proposition that E can represent as F\W there both F and W is close in X. Am I right?

Comment: @VDGG: Yes, $F\setminus W=R\cap(X\setminus W$, so it’s the intersection of a closed and an open set.